# CSS background-size and div size

Tags: html, image, css

I'm trying to create an overlay on an image using `<img src="picture">`. However, using background-color in CSS does not show since the picture is blocking the background. Is there a way to create a color that overlaps the picture?

I have tried using the picture has `background-image:url(picture);` but to my understanding, background-image does not dictate the `<img>` size but if you use `<img src="picture">, you're picture size will form the`` size. And I need the image to render proportionally to the window.

I need some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

This shows a container with a background color with a image over it and image also reflects the color of its background.

**Fiddle link** : http://jsfiddle.net/4AtGn/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container"> 
    <img class="cont-img" src="http://www.businessinsider.in/photo/37988660/These-Are-11-Wealthiest-Women-In-Tech.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container{
    background-color:#090;
    width:100%;
}

.cont-img{
    opacity:0.8;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Image Overlay Techniques:**

**Using `background-image`:** If you prefer background-image then i would just using :after element and applying opacity to it. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/BaXLA/)**

**Using `<img>` tag:** You can use `opacity: 0.1;` max value `1`, this will make your image transparent & you will be able to see the background image. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/BaXLA/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
   <div class="first-stack">
      <img src="http://www.businessinsider.in/photo/37988660/These-Are-11-Wealthiest-Women-In-Tech.jpg"/>
   </div>

    <div class="overlay"> 
    </div>

    <div class="top-stack">
       <img src="http://www.businessinsider.in/photo/37988660/These-Are-11-Wealthiest-Women-In-Tech.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.top-stack {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-339px;
    margin-top:-255px;

}
```

See The **Fiddle Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/Jyw8S/